# unable to print augeas for own configuration

Tags: puppet, augeas

I have below dtp.conf file for internal requirement.

```
/opt/dtp/etc/dtp.conf

export CHO='NON-PROD'
```

but when I print the config file via augtool unable to print the value

```
/opt/pupet/bin/augtool
augtool> print /files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config
augtool>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not remember Augeas having a specific lens for this file. Augeas cannot guess which lens (parser) to use, it needs to know which lens to associate to which file.

In this case, this looks like a Shellvar type of file, so you can use e.g.:

```
augtool -At "Shellvars.lns incl /opt/dtp/etc/dtp.conf"
```

to edit it.

In Puppet, use the `shellvar` type from the [augeasproviders_shellvar](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/herculesteam/augeasproviders_shellvar) Puppet module:

```
shellvar { 'CHO':
  ensure => exported,
  target => '/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config',
  value  => 'NON-PROD',
}
```

Comment: I wrote below manifests  shellvar { "export CHO":
   ensure => present,
  target => "/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config",
  value => "Non - prod" but getting error "Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type shellvar at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/example/manifests/dtp.pp:14 on node" augtool version is 1.3.0

Comment: Yes, I tried you "shellvars" snippet but getting "Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type shellvar at /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/modules/example/manifests/dtp.pp:14 on node.  Is there any problem with my puppet version. I am using puppet version3.8

Comment: Did you install augeasproviders_shellvar and dependencies (augeasproviders_core)?

Comment: yes. I installed aueasproviders_shellvar and augeasproviders_core. But now I am getting "Error: /Stage[main]/Example::Cho/Shellvar[CHO]: Could not evaluate: Augeas didn't load /opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config with Shellvars.lns: Syntax error"

Comment: When you launch puppet in debug mode, it will tell you which line fails to parse. Can you paste that line? Also, which version of augeas are you using?

Comment: I ran with debug mode " puppet apply -t  --debug dtp.pp"  but not showing any line number  Debug: Loaded state in 0.11 seconds
Info: Applying configuration version '1445573638'
Error: /Stage[main]/Example::Dtp/Shellvar[DTP]: Could not evaluate: Augeas didn't load /opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config with Shellvars.lns: Syntax error"  and augeas version is augeasversion => 1.3.0

Comment: You could try running the file through augtool to check if augeas understands it: `augtool -At "Shellvars.lns incl /opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config" print /augeas//error`

Comment: I am getting below error root@puppet ~]#/opt/puppet/bin/augtool -At "Shellvars.lns incl /opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config" print /augeas//error
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error = "parse_failed"
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error/pos = "0"
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error/line = "1"
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error/char = "0"
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error/lens = "/opt/puppet/share/augeas/lenses/dist/shellvars.aug:191.12-.56:"
/augeas/files/opt/dtp/etc/dtp_config/error/message = "Syntax error"

Comment: What is line 1 of your file?

Comment: Thanks Raphkin for your help. The comment line of the file was uncommented by mistake. I comment it out again and manifests is working. But I have another doubt, when I run manifest first time got **DTP="NON-PROD"** instead of **export DTP="NON-PROD**  when I run second time getting **"Notice: /Stage[main]/Example::Dtp/Shellvar[DTP]/ensure: ensure changed 'present' to 'exported'** and the o/p is **export DTP="NON-PROD** why the word **export** missing when I run first time.

Comment: Can you report a bug on this? I think I remember seeing this before but I'm not sure...

Comment: should I raise any ticket for this in puppet blog? if so, please send me the details.

Comment: Please report this against the github project for augeasproviders_shellvar

Comment: created bug report https://github.com/hercules-team/augeasproviders_shellvar/issues/20

Comment: downloaded augeas provider 2.2.1 version and it worked. Thanks :)